# How can I receive actions listed in here? (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, action

[image]

I'm trying to connection the actions to specific object in IB tree. When I drag the action from the circle on the right side of each action name, no object accepts the line except `NSScroller` instance.

`NSWIndow`, `NSResponder` or any other kind of objects doesn't accept the dragged action. What's required to accept the action listed here?

Comment: @Grady I modified my question to clarify more.

Answer (score 1):

These are action messages that you can send to the selected object (i.e., that it can receive and respond to). You can drag from any of those circles to any object (most probably a control, most probably a button) that has a target and an action; doing so will set the control's target property to this object and the control's action property to the action you connected it to.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a  delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
```

Here's a usage: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/48070-adding-carriage-return-behavior-to-nstextview.html